# Convert uploaded image to Base64 string

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadPassfoto" runat="server" 
                Width="100%" Style="background-color: #533473; border-color: lightgray;" />
```

This is my FileUpload created with asp.net. Only images will be uploaded!
In my C# Code Behind i tried this code:

```
HttpPostedFile file = FileUploadPassfoto.PostedFile;
using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
{
    lehrling.passfoto = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength));
}
```

lehrling.passfoto is a string variable. When i debug through my code. the lehrling.passfoto has the value "". So an empty string. What am i doing wrong? The httppostedfile works just fine. The filepath and contentlenght are correct....
Any suggestions

Comment: Have you verified that `binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength)` is returning any data?

Comment: its not a duplicate. i didnt ask for a path... read my question properly. I dont NEED A PATH!!!!!! @aristos